# How to exclude dependencies in aether collectDependencies

Tags: java, maven, aether

I want to build something similar to `mvn dependency:tree`. If a dependency has an `exclusions` tag, then its transitive dependencies will not be shown in the resolved result.

However, I try to have something similar to the [demo example](https://github.com/apache/maven-resolver/blob/master/maven-resolver-demos/maven-resolver-demo-snippets/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/resolver/examples/GetDependencyTree.java), where I add an exclusion to a dependency, hoping to exclude all its transitive dependencies of this library, but it still prints the full tree.

```
RepositorySystem system = Booter.newRepositorySystem(Booter.selectFactory(args));

RepositorySystemSession session = Booter.newRepositorySystemSession(system);
Artifact artifact1 = new DefaultArtifact("com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.31.5");
Exclusion exclusion = new Exclusion("*", "*", null, null);
CollectRequest collectRequest = new CollectRequest();
collectRequest.setRepositories(Booter.newRepositories(system, session));
collectRequest.setDependencies(List.of(new Dependency(artifact1, "", false, Set.of(exclusion))));
CollectResult collectResult = system.collectDependencies(session, collectRequest);

collectResult.getRoot().accept(new ConsoleDependencyGraphDumper());
```